# Can not load javascript from my module (via addScript)

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am creating custom template and module, and for now it is working, but at the moment I can not load javascript from my module. This is code inside my module:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . '/modules/mod_homenewslist/js/newslist.js');
```

I am guessing that this have something to do with me loading CSS and JS old fashion way (I don't like default Joomla way of loading files into head - to many files). This is my head:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <?php $title = $this->getTitle(); ?>

  <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
  <link href="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/css/template.css">
  <script src="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/js/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/js/cycle.js"></script>
  <script src="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/js/jfontsize.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="templates/pidizajnoptinapirottemplate/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong? If I need to load files Joomla way in order so that module script can be loaded, how can I load only files that I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to load jQuery using `<script>` tags. This can simply be done using the following which loads it in noConflict mode:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

also, as for your module script, try removing the first forward slash "/" before "modules", like so:

```
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . 'modules/mod_homenewslist/js/newslist.js');
```

**Update:**

Found the issue. Add the following to your template index.php file right below the `<head>` tag:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

The gets all scripts, stylesheets and other data that you apply using `$doc->`.

Comment: I changed jQuery, and module as you suggested, but script from module is still not loading. Does this have something to do with me using addScript from default.php (module layout)?

Comment: no, there's nothing wrong with the code. silly question, but are you sure the file is actually there?

Comment: Not a silly question - file is there, module is working and I am getting layout, and I did a double check on JS file. I also made newslist.php, to try instead of js file, but it is not working.

Comment: do you think you would be able to provide a copy of the module zip?

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but I am kinda stuck, and still without solution - any thoughts about the problem?

Comment: Just about to test now

Comment: Ok, just tested the module without any edits on Joomla 3.2 and it works fine for me. The script is being imported. If you change the template on your site to the default Joomla template (Protostar), do you then see the `newslist.js` file being imported?

Comment: When I changed template, the script is loading (I never considerate doing this o.O). I am guessing this have something to do with my head not loading scripts Joomla way.

Comment: Maybe, weel seeing as you're module is working fine, you can zip up the template and I can test that for you if you wish

Comment: That was the problem - I off to Joomla documentation to find a way to get read of all extra files. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at the Protostar template to see how files should be imported in a template `index.php` file. It's similar to yours but with a few changes. But simply remember to import jQuery the way I showed you in my answer ;)